# How to understand this fragment?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I'm currently reading a book and stumbled upon this paragraph I have trouble understanding.

> Previously the inhabitants of Mecca used to buy slaves and imposed a
>   financial contribution on them which was to be paid to their master
>   daily. Similarly the women imposed a contribution on their slave girls
>   in order to get money. **So the slave girl [simply] hopes for
>   alleviation [from her financial burden] or she gives freely of her
>   vagina to the man and promiscuity runs amok.** This is still found in
>   Aden among outsiders and locals and they do not regard this practice
>   as a shameful act. On the contrary, women [even] boast of doing this.

My main question is about the sentence in bold. I'm especially puzzled by the usage of `or` in this sentence (she hopes for giving freely of her vagina?)...

Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The sentence has two alternatives and an end result: 
1.She does nothing and hopes that one day her financial burden will be removed: **hopes for alleviation [from her financial burden]** 
OR 
2. She sells her body: **she gives freely of her vagina** Note The purpose of giving her vagina to the man (men) is to gain money so therefore it can be deduced that freely in this context is not meant as free of charge but **wantonly, Unrestrained or excessively.**
The outcome of the second option is that  **promiscuity runs amok**